# What changes are to be made in code to move from Feathers nedb to Postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, feathersjs

I have used feathers-nedb library and wrote a server code in Node. Now I need to shift to Postgres DB. I have written models and data insert queries in feathers-nedb so is there way I don't mess up with the structure, but connect to Postgres instead and run the code.

Comment: I don't think you are going to find a 1:1 here. These are two very different database products :/

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. You can use the feathers-knex library. Just change the nedb model to feathers-knex and create a Model using knex Postgres connection string.

```
const dbPath = app.get('nedb');
const Model = new NeDB({
    filename: path.join(dbPath, 'test.db'),
    autoload: true
});

const Model = new knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: "postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/test",
    searchPath: ['knex', 'public'],
});
```

This is the only code change that is required on the Model side. On the service side, instead of feathers-nedb use feathers-knex.